# Divide multiple columns by another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to divide all but the first columns in a DataFrame by the first column.

Here's what I'm doing, but I wonder if this isn't the "right" pandas way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3), columns=list('ABC'))

df[['B', 'C']] = (df.T.iloc[1:] / df.T.iloc[0]).T
```

Is there a way to do something like `df[['B','C']] / df['A']`? (That just gives a 10x12 dataframe of `nan`.)

Also, after reading some similar questions on SO, I tried `df['A'].div(df[['B', 'C']])` but that gives a broadcast error.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

I believe `df[['B','C']].div(df.A, axis=0)` and `df.iloc[:,1:].div(df.A, axis=0)` work.

Comment: This works great, but the resulting data frame is missing other columns that are not used in the above division. For example, if there is a column D that is not divided by A, the resulting data frame is missing column D and the column A. Any way to overcome this?

Comment: I think I found a way for my data set. I moved the column D to index using pd.set_index() and after the division got back to the data set.

Comment: @NAGA, does your method of moving one column `D` to index work if you have multiple columns to ignore (ie to not divide through)?

Comment: @alancalvitti it worked. I tried moving two of my columns to index using set_index() and then performed the division operation. I got back my columns using reset_index() without any problem. Also, one of my columns had duplicate values and it did not create any problem when I moved it to index.

Comment: I believe you can also do `df.loc[:, cols] = df.loc[:, cols].div(df['A'], axis=0)`, to only divide a subset of the columns

Comment: no need to move column D to index, just do this: `df[['B','C']] = df[['B','C']].div(df.A, axis=0)`. All other columns are preserved in the dataframe `df`

Comment: why does it not broadcast by default?

Answer (score 10):

```
do: df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].div(df.A, axis=0)
```

This will divide all columns other than the *1st column* with the *'A'* column used as divisor.

Results are `1st column + all columns after / 'divisor column'`.

Answer (score 3):

You are actually doing a matrix multiplication (*Apparently numpy understands that "/" operator multiplies by the inverse*), so you need the shapes to match (see [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-multiplying.html)).

e.g.

`df['A'].shape` --> (10,)
`df[['B','C']].shape` --> (10,2)

You should make them match as (2,10)(10,):
`df[['B','C']].T.shape, df['A'].shape` -->((2, 10), (10,))

But then your resulting matrix is:
`( df[['B','C']].T / df['A'] ).shape` --> (2,10)

Therefore:

```
( df[['B','C']].T / df['A'] ).T
```

Shape is (10,2). It gives you the results that you wanted!