# Dividing one column in a dataframe by a number while bringing back all other columns in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, division

I am trying to divide one column in a dataframe by a number while bringing back all other columns in a dataframe unchanged. The code below works for the division, but I dont know how to bring back the columns I wanted unchanged from the dataframe as well:

```
df= df[['C']].div(4, axis = 0)
```

the data looks like this

[image]

The output that I am looking for would be:

[image]

The closest I could find to an answer is here:[Divide multiple columns by another column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34540567/divide-multiple-columns-by-another-column-in-pandas)

However, the last quote says to use pd.set_index after the division, but I am not sure how that syntax is supposed to look.

Right now I am only getting the output column C not the two other columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
df['C']= df['C']/4
```

It will divide the column C by 4 while keeping other columns same.

You are getting the output column C only because you are saving column C changed only:

```
df['C']= df[['C']].div(4, axis=0)
```

This may give you the exact result

Comment: When I go to Print df it is still only showing the division output, not the other columns A and B.

Comment: Have you used  df['C']= df['C']/4 . It should give you the desired output. Can you share the whole code.

Comment: new_df = df['C'] = df[['C']].div(4, axis=0) print(new_df)

Comment: Dude. You are doing it in a wrong way. You are changing the column C with this df[['C']].div(4, axis=0) and the you are storing it into new_df. So only column 'C' will get changed and stored. By doing df['C']= df['C']/4 only C column will get changed. Then you can print df. It will show you the changes.