# Divide several columns with the same column name ending by one other column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a smiliar question to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34540567/divide-multiple-columns-by-another-column-in-pandas).

I have a dataframe with several rows, which looks like this:

```
Name   TypA   TypB ... TypF TypA_value TypB_value ... TypF_value Divider
1       1      1        NaN     10        5             NaN         5
2       NaN    2        NaN     NaN       20            NaN         10
```

and I want to divide all columns with the ending "value" by the column "Divider", how can I do so? One trick would be to use the sorting, to use the answer from above, but is there a direct way for it? That I do not need to sort the dataframe.

The outcome would be:

```
Name   TypA   TypB ... TypF TypA_value TypB_value ... TypF_value Divider
1       1      1        NaN     2        1             0         5
2       NaN    2        NaN     0        2             0         10
```

So a NaN will lead to a 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to filter the columns like `value` from dataframe then use [`DataFrame.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) along `axis=0` to divide it by column `Divider`, finally use [`DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) to update the values in dataframe:

```
d = df.filter(like='_value').div(df['Divider'], axis=0).fillna(0)
df.update(d)
```

Result:

```
   Name  TypA  TypB  TypF  TypA_value  TypB_value  TypF_value  Divider
0     1   1.0     1   NaN         2.0         1.0         0.0        5
1     2   NaN     2   NaN         0.0         2.0         0.0       10
```

Comment: What is the function, If I decide to multiple the value? instead `div` what do I need to use then?

Comment: @PV8 I think u can use `mul`

Answer (score 2):

You could select the columns of interest using [`DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), and divide as:

```
value_cols = df.filter(regex=r'_value$').columns
df[value_cols] /= df['Divider'].to_numpy()[:,None]
# df[value_cols] = df[value_cols].fillna(0)
```

---

```
print(df)

   Name  TypA  TypB  TypF  TypA_value  TypB_value  TypF_value  Divider
0     1   1.0     1   NaN         2.0         1.0         NaN        5
1     2   NaN     2   NaN         NaN         2.0         NaN       10
```

Comment: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float' `seems my dataframe is not so good structured

Comment: Nope. Cast to numeric in that case @PV8

Answer (score 0):

Taking two sample columns A and B :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a={ 'Name':[1,2],
    'TypA':[1,np.nan],
    'TypB':[1,2],
    'TypA_value':[10,np.nan],
    'TypB_value':[5,20],
    'Divider':[5,10]
   }
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
cols_all = df.columns
```

Find columns for which calculations are to be done. Assuming there all have 'value' and an underscore :

```
cols_to_calc = [c for c in cols_all if '_value' in c]
```

For these columns: first, divide with the divider column then replace nan with 0 in those columns.

```
for c in cols_to_calc:
    df[c] = df[c] / df.Divider
    df[c] = df[c].fillna(0)
```