# Dividing Dataframes with Different Dimensions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I prefer to use matrix multiplication for coding, because it's so much more efficient than iterating, but curious on how to do this if the dimensions are different.

I have two different dataframes

A:

| Orig_vintage |  |
| --- | --- |
| Q12018 | 185 |
| Q22018. | 200 |

and B:

| default_month | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| orig_vintage |  |  |  |
| Q12018 | 0 | 25 | 35 |
| Q22018 | 0 | 15 | 45 |
| Q32018 | 0 | 35 | 65 |

and I'm trying to divide A through columns of B, so the B dataframe becomes (note I've rounded random percentages):

| default_month | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| orig_vintage |  |  |  |
| Q12018 | 0 | .03 | .04 |
| Q22018 | 0 | .04 | .05 |
| Q32018 | 0 | .06 | .07 |

But bottom line want to divide the monthly defaults by the total origination figure to get to a monthly default %.

Answer (score 0):

- first step is get data side by side with a **right** `join()`
- then divide all columns by required value [Divide multiple columns by another column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34540567/divide-multiple-columns-by-another-column-in-pandas)
- required value as I understand is sum, if join did not give a value.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df1 = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO("""Orig_vintage,Unnamed: 1\nQ12018,185\nQ22018,200\n"""), sep=","
)

df2 = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        """default_month,1,2,3\nQ12018,0.0,25.0,35.0\nQ22018,0.0,15.0,45.0\nQ32018,0.0,35.0,65.0\n"""
    ),
    sep=",",
)

df1.set_index("Orig_vintage").join(df2.set_index("default_month"), how="right").pipe(
    lambda d: d.div(d["Unnamed: 1"].fillna(d["Unnamed: 1"].sum()), axis=0)
)
```

| default_month | Unnamed: 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Q12018 | 1 | 0 | 0.135135 | 0.189189 |
| Q22018 | 1 | 0 | 0.075 | 0.225 |
| Q32018 | nan | 0 | 0.0909091 | 0.168831 |